# joomla article error

Tags: php, wampserver, joomla2.5

I am getting this error after installing joomla when I login to the joomla homepage...
How can I resolve this error?
It's a call stack error.
On these functions it is giving this error message:

```
(!) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\Joomla\components\com_content\models\articles.php on line 124

    Time    Memory  Function       Location    
1   0.0106  147704  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0

2   4.1993  3885048 JSite->dispatch( )  ..\index.php:42

3   4.2998  4098608 JComponentHelper::renderComponent( )    ..\application.php:197

4   4.3968  4122720 JComponentHelper::executeComponent( )   ..\helper.php:351

5   4.3976  4142608 require_once( '6    4.5327  4384488 JController->execute( ) ..\content.php:16

6   4.5327  4384488 JController->execute( ) ..\content.php:16

7   4.5327  4384632 ContentController->display( )   ..\controller.php:760

8   4.7422  4878680 JController->display( ) ..\controller.php:74

9   4.8532  5211688 ContentViewFeatured->display( ) ..\controller.php:721

10  4.8556  5214224 JView->get( )   ..\view.html.php:40

11  4.8556  5214344 ContentModelFeatured->getItems( )   ..\view.php:386

12  4.8560  5223336 ContentModelArticles->getItems( )   ..\featured.php:80


13  4.8560  5223832 JModelList->getItems( ) ..\articles.php:476

14  4.8561  5223952 ContentModelFeatured->getStoreId( ) ..\modellist.php:118

15  4.8561  5224024 ContentModelArticles->getStoreId( ) ..\featured.php:102
```

Comment: This log is only the call stack. Please post the complete error message.

Comment: Please format your code as a block by indenting it, don't do it line by line like that.

Comment: first column shows error number second shows time, third shows memory, fourth show function and last one is location.

Comment: Maybe it is a memory issue. Please try increase your memory_limit in your php.ini file  to 128M or 256M

Comment: my memory limit is already 128M

Comment: I changed my memory limit which is 128M to 256M but no change in the error

Answer (score 2):

Go to administrator
Login
CLICK Site=>Global Configuration->Server tab
CLICK Error Reporting drop down list
CLICK Simple
CLICK Save and Close
Refresh your Web browser on the site page and the notices will be gone.

The issue itself is caused by a bug in PHP 5.4.x, which is now installed with XAMPP 1.8., it is only an advisory notice and therefore nothing is "broken" yet. There is a chance that you might experience issues later on but the Joomla developers are aware of the issue and keeping a close eye on developments.